# Yesod Hardcoded authentication depending on AppSettings

Tags: haskell, monads, yesod

I am trying to setup the hardcoded authentification to rely on login information specified in `config/settings.yml` from the Yesod scaffolding. I wrote the following code:

```
instance YesodAuthHardcoded App where
    validatePassword u = do
        app <- getYesod
        let user = appUser $ appSettings app
        return . validPassword user u . fromString . unpack
    doesUserNameExist = do
        app <- getYesod
        return . isJust . lookupUser app
```

And I receive the following error message for `validatePassord` and the equivalent for `doesUserNameExist`:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘HandlerSite ((->) Text)’ with ‘App’
  Expected type: Text -> App
    Actual type: Text -> HandlerSite ((->) Text)
• In a stmt of a 'do' block: app <- getYesod
  In the expression:
    do { app <- getYesod;
         let user = appUser $ appSettings app;
         return . validPassword user u . fromString . unpack }
  In an equation for ‘validatePassword’:
      validatePassword u
        = do { app <- getYesod;
               let user = ...;
               return . validPassword user u . fromString . unpack }
```

The prototype of `validatePassword` [is defined in `Yesod.Auth.Hardcoded`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.12/yesod-auth-1.6.3/Yesod-Auth-Hardcoded.html):

```
validatePassword :: Text -> Text -> AuthHandler site Bool
```

and `AuthHandler` [is defined in `Yesod.Auth`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.12/yesod-auth-1.6.3/Yesod-Auth.html#t:AuthHandler):

```
type MonadAuthHandler master m = (MonadHandler m, YesodAuth master, master ~ HandlerSite m, Auth ~ SubHandlerSite m, MonadUnliftIO m)

type AuthHandler master a = forall m. MonadAuthHandler master m => m a
```

Finally `getYesod` [is defined as follow in `Yesod.Core.Handler`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.11/yesod-core-1.4.37/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v:getYesod):

```
getYesod :: MonadHandler m => m (HandlerSite m)
```

It seems from these definitions that there should be a way for me to call `getYesod` from the `AuthHandler` monad but I can't figure out how.

---

EDIT:
I have updated `yesod` and its scaffolding to the latest version. I also modified `validatePassword` as follow:

```
validatePassword u = do
    app <- liftHandler . getYesod
    let user = appUser $ appSettings app
    return . validPassword user u . fromString . unpack
```

And I get the following error message:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘m1 a1’ with ‘App’
      Expected type: HandlerFor (HandlerSite m1) a1 -> App
        Actual type: HandlerFor (HandlerSite m1) a1 -> m1 a1
    • In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘liftHandler’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: app <- liftHandler . getYesod
      In the expression:
        do app <- liftHandler . getYesod
           let user = appUser $ appSettings app
           return . validPassword user u . fromString . unpack
    |
259 |         app <- liftHandler . getYesod
    |
```

Comment: I suspect you need to plug `liftHandler` or `liftSubHandler` somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error came from my attempt at modifying the code snippet given by the `Yesod.Auth.Hardcoded` module. I introduced a `do` notation that conflicted with the omitted arguments. Specifying the arguments solves the issue, the code becomes:

```
instance YesodAuthHardcoded App where
    validatePassword u p = do
        app <- getYesod
        let user = appUser $ appSettings app
        return . validPassword user u . fromString $ unpack p
    doesUserNameExist u = do
        app <- getYesod
        return . isJust $ lookupUser app u
```